# Arrays: Join two arrays in one

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have two arrays:

```
$array1 = 
   [
     0 =>
       [
         'data1' => value1
       ],
     1 =>
       [
          'data1' => value2
       ]
   ];



   $array2 = 
   [
     0 =>
       [
         'data2' => value1
       ],
     1 =>
       [
          'data2' => value2
       ]
   ];
```

Only i want create this:

```
   $arrayFinish = 
   [
     0 =>
       [
         'data1' => value1,
         'data2' => value1
       ],
     1 =>
       [
          'data1' => value2
          'data2' => value2
       ]
   ];
```

I have done this:

```
 foreach ($data1 as $key=>$val)
           {
               $arrayFinish[] =
                   [
                       $val,

                   ];

               foreach ($data2[$key] as $key2=>$val2)
               {
                  array_push($arrayFinish[$key],['data2'=>$val2]);
               }
           }
```

My actually result:

```
    array:2 [▼
         0 => array:2 [▼
            0 => {#1546 ▼
             +"data1": "BWQHCLJCH"
            }
            1 => {#1547 ▼
            +"data2": "00308F000825"
          }
        ]
        1 => array:2 [▼
          0 => {#1548 ▼
            +"data1": "OTGSAVJIU"
           }
          1 => {#1549 ▼
            +"data2": "00308F000946"
          }
         ]
        ]
```

I am trying to do it using PHP. I am blocked right now, i am sure that that the solution is using two loops, but i am doing any bad. If you can see my actually result is not similar to my wish result.

thank u for the help.

Comment: what have you tried to achieve this?

Comment: foreach ($array1 as $key=>$val)
               {
                   foreach ($array2 as $key2=>$val2)
                   {
                      $arrayFinish [] =
                      [
                        $val,
                        $val2
                      ];
                   }
               } But i know that this is very bad.

Comment: @joseangarita You should always include your attempt in your question itself.

Comment: This is a duplicate question that does not require any new answers to be resolved. [array_map('array_merge', $array1, $array2)](https://3v4l.org/udsJU)

Answer (score 0):

Thank u to all that tried to help me. I find a solution.

I am tried to clear the array

```
 foreach ($array1 as $key=>$val)
           {

               $arrayFinish[$key] = $val;


               foreach ($array2[$key] as $key2=>$val2)
               {
                  array_push($arrayFinish[$key],["data2"=>$val2]);
               }
           }
```

Using a for cycle i can have access using one iteration to the information. This is not the great solution that i tried to find but working.

Best regards

Answer (score -1):

if your both arrays would have same no of indexes then you can do using below code

```
foreach ($array1 as $key=>$val) {
    $arrayFinish [] = [ $array1[$key], $array2[$key] ];
}
```

Comment: This isn't the solution that i try to find. Thank u

Comment: my solution was based on what information you gave you want as output. so you cant mark my answer as negative as your question itself was giving wrong info. please mention what exactly output you want as my solution will give you the output mentioned in the question

Comment: I explained in the statement, what arrays i have, what is the result that i am try to find and  i show the code that i created. Your solution create an array inside to other array, please if you really want help me, please read the statement and you can understand what i am try to obtain, if you read my explaination you can see that i have the same result that you propose. Thank u.